# Is a question about how to deal with XRaying as an admin on Minecraft Multiplayer on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Would a question like this be considered on-topic for arqade? I want to know if it's on-topic before posting it.

Comment: I think it _should_ be. A lot depends on how you write it though.

Comment: @badp What kind of things should I watch out for as I write it?

Comment: It's probably easier to tell once you do write it :) but in general, [this is a good start.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On topic? Yes. Whether it's Constructive or A Real Question depends on how open-ended/concretely-answerable it is and how vague/complete it is. But most certainly the base subject matter is on topic.